# How to make Javascript more specific?

Tags: javascript

I am new at JavaScript so I think my problem may be simple.
This works:

```
var convId = document.getElementById("wrapper");
convId.setAttribute("align","right");
```

But when I try to make it more specific:

```
var convId = document.getElementById("wrapper");
var convIdDl = convId.getElementsByTagName("dl");
convIdDl.setAttribute("align","right");
```

my definition list doesn't align to the right.
I have checked the HTML and CSS and everything is correct, but that shouldn't even matter
JavaScript overwrites them both.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName) method returns a collection (to be more specific, a `NodeList`). You need to specify which element of that collection you want to use (just like you would when accessing an element in an array). Here I'm assuming you want the first:

```
convIdDl[0].setAttribute("align", "right");
```

As noted in the comments, you should definitely not be using the `align` attribute. CSS should be used in all cases.

Comment: Plus the align attribute is deprecrated anyways. This should be done via CSS rules.

Comment: You can use javascript to assign a class to elements. So you can use the javascript as a fancy selector mechanism AND still reap the benefits of using true CSS for the actual layout.

Comment: Thanks and I wasn't actually using the align attribute in JavaScript, I was just practicing with it.

Answer (score 4):

The `getElementsByTagName()` function returns a collection of DOM elements, so you'll probably want to iterate through that and set the attribute on each element individually.

```
for(var i = 0; i < convIdDl.length; i++) {
    convIdDl[i].setAttribute("align", "right");
}
```